# "Failed to upload *.app on Device " Error in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting an error while uploading my app on device. It does installs it but not able to upload it.

Also I want to run the instrument tool on device but when I run it shows nothing.

Anyone facing the same issues.

Answer (score 120):

I had this problem after changing around provisioning profiles and app ID's.

What fixed it for me:

1. Quit XCode
2. In Terminal.app, navigate to your project directory and execute `rm -rf build/`
3. Restart XCode

Comment: Another well-deserved upvote from me. Now that I see that, you could probably just go "Build > Clean all Targets" and achieve the same result.

Comment: "Clean All Targets" doesn't fix this error.  You definitely have to follow the steps detailed here to get rid of the error.

Comment: Confirming that, "Clean All Targets" does not fix it.

Comment: I would just note that for beginners, step 2 could be expanded to be: 2a. Start Terminal.app   2b. rm -rf build/  It worked for me but since I didn't know what that terminal command meant, I was unsure if that was all there was to it.  It was.

Comment: Archie, that was a painful problem you helped solve. Remind me to never change Bundle Identifiers ever again. Thanks!

Comment: This (rm -rf build/) is definitely required.  Clean All does not do what needs to be done.

Comment: Clean all worked, for me, but just had to be sure to restart xcode.

Comment: Clean All Targets, then restart XCode fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it would be really helpful if you expanded step 2 to make sense for people who are not used to Terminal.app... Most importantly, you need to navigate to your project's directory in Terminal before you can run that command.

Comment: Clean All/Restart XCode. Whenever something weird happens, that's my regular fix. Works 9 times out of 10 for provisioning/device install weirdness.

Comment: am running iOS beta3 on iPad and Xcode3 (I can’t upgrade to Xcode4 yet), doesn’t work for me.

Answer (score 6):

I also confirm, that I had that issue on Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2 GM Seed and after adding new provisioning profile.

You do not have to use terminal, you can select *.app from Products Group in 'Groups & Files' pane in Xcode. Then right-click on it, and select 'Reveal in finder'. Then manually delete the build catalogue. And restart Xcode.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this issue on an iPhone running 3.0 software, but it was working fine on phones running 3.1. The app used to work on the 3.0 software until we added users to the provisioning for the app - this is the only thing I can think of that might have caused it.

If you're running 3.0 still, try upgrading to 3.1 and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message in iOS 4.1 but from a different cause: when trying to link to a universal (ARM & X86) static library that was over 10MB. If I link directly to the ARM version of the static library (for iPhones), then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes manual delete of Build folder of your application fails to solve the problem
"Failed to upload the .app on device"

Try
WIndows->organizer->Provisioning profile(in left pane)->refresh it once....

This has solved my problem!